# Sikuli interact with more than 1 matching object

Tags: sikuli

Hello so for example I have 4 balls that I must right click on, but when I right click them, nothing about the balls changes, how can I make it so that sikuli right clicks each of the balls and doesn't just get stuck on one of them?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a for loop to search for all the balls. 
Then in the for loop you can define what to do with it once found.

For example (Sikuli with Python):

```
Image_Balls = ()
for x in findAll(Image_Balls):
     click(x)
```

Between the () you need to place a picture of how a ball looks like. 
In this example he will find every ball on the screen and click on it. 
You can also add a try, catch/exception in the for loop.

Then he will find every ball, and try to right click. 
If the try failed, he will execute the catch (exception in python). 
And will continue to look for the next ball, until there are no anymore.

```
Image_Balls = ()
for x in findAll(Image_Balls):
     try:
          rightClick(x)
     except:
          pass
```